# android: fastest way to display loading screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have a gles based game that takes quite some time to load because of the huge amount of textures.

now i want to display a loading-text or loading-bar as soon as possible as the application is starting up.

what is the fastest way to display a text like this? should i do it in gles as well or should i use an alert or view?

Answer (score 4):

I made a separate loading screen activity in my game that uses the standard Android UI.  It has a text view saying "Loading" and a ProgressBar that gets incremented as it loads in images, sounds, etc. from disk into memory (I put all filenames into a stack and then pop them off one at a time and increment the ProgressBar after I pop something off the stack).  When the loading is done, it takes the user to a main menu activity, and from there they can start my game.

Comment: @clamp by calling an Intent like so: Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Game.class);  startActivity(i);

Comment: ok thanks, that brings up the loadingactivity unfortunately once the textureloading is finished i now get an  java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC, probably because some gl stuff is executed in the wrong thread

Comment: @clamp I haven't done any openGL on Android, only 2D graphics using Android drawing libraries.  If you still have a problem, it might warrant asking a new question to get help